# NumPy - calculate histogram intersection

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, histogram

The following data, represent 2 given histograms split into 13 bins:

```
key 0   1-9 10-18   19-27   28-36   37-45   46-54   55-63   64-72   73-81   82-90   91-99   100
A   1.274580708 2.466224824 5.045757621 7.413716262 8.958855646 10.41325305 11.14150951 10.91949012 11.29095648 10.95054297 10.10976255 8.128781795 1.886568472
B   0   1.700493692 4.059243006 5.320899616 6.747120132 7.899067471 9.434997257 11.24520022 12.94569391 12.83598464 12.6165661  10.80636314 4.388370817
```

[image]

I'm trying to follow [this article](http://blog.datadive.net/histogram-intersection-for-change-detection/) in order to calculate the intersection between those 2 histograms, using this method:

```
def histogram_intersection(h1, h2, bins):
   bins = numpy.diff(bins)
   sm = 0
   for i in range(len(bins)):
       sm += min(bins[i]*h1[i], bins[i]*h2[i])
   return sm
```

Since my data is already calculated as a histogram, I can't use numpy built-in function, so I'm failing to provide the function the necessary data.

How can I process my data to fit the algorithm?

Comment: What is the issue with the function you show? Looks adequate to me, at a glance.

Comment: The function expects bins generated by the histogram method. I only have the histogram data.

Comment: What about directly `np.minimum(A, B)` since the bins are the same for both A and B?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 7):

Since you have the same number of bins for both of the histograms you can use:

```
def histogram_intersection(h1, h2):
    sm = 0
    for i in range(13):
        sm += min(h1[i], h2[i])
    return sm
```

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate it faster and more simply with Numpy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

A = np.array([1.274580708,2.466224824,5.045757621,7.413716262,8.958855646,10.41325305,11.14150951,10.91949012,11.29095648,10.95054297,10.10976255,8.128781795,1.886568472])
B = np.array([0,1.700493692,4.059243006,5.320899616,6.747120132,7.899067471,9.434997257,11.24520022,12.94569391,12.83598464,12.6165661,10.80636314,4.388370817])

def histogram_intersection(h1, h2):
    sm = 0
    for i in range(13):
        sm += min(h1[i], h2[i])
    return sm

print(histogram_intersection(A,B))
print(np.sum(np.minimum(A,B)))
```

**Output**

```
88.44792356099998
88.447923561
```

But if you time it, Numpy only takes 60% of the time:

```
%timeit histogram_intersection(A,B)
5.02 µs ± 65.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.sum(np.minimum(A,B))
3.22 µs ± 11.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Im trying to compare two color histograms but get this error VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested 
sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return np.sum(np.minimum(hist_1,hist_2))

Answer (score 1):

Some caveats first : in your data bins are ranges, in your algorithm they are numbers. You must redefine bins for that.

Furthermore, `min(bins[i]*h1[i], bins[i]*h2[i])` is `bins[i]*min(h1[i], h2[i])`, so the result can be obtained by :

```
hists=pandas.read_clipboard(index_col=0) # your data
bins=arange(-4,112,9)   #  try for bins but edges are different here
mins=hists.min('rows')
intersection=dot(mins,bins)
```